# How to use session two different methods

Tags: session, struts2

First of all i am going fetch students of a particular class by clicking search button so ill get a list students. then i have two option in UI export in excel format(m1 method) and export in pdf format(m2 method) to do this 
so that arraylist i have to keep in session because i have make available arraylist for those two methods

**Code**

```
public class Test extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware {

    private Map<String, Object> session;

    public String execute() throws Exception {

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = // from db

        return "";

    }

    public String m1() throws Exception {

        return "";

    }

    public String m2() throws Exception {

        return "";

    }

    public void setSession(Map session) {
        this.session = session;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean *use session two different methods*? Are those methods mapped to the actions?

Comment: Ya. those methods are mapped to different actions

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. If you want to keep a collection in the session then put it in the session, with the caveat that keeping ginormous blobs of data in the session can have implications.

Answer (score 0):

When storing state in the session, its important to give thought to scenarios where a user within the same session opens the same view in multiple browser tabs and renders said view with different contexts, e.g. different search parameters if your case.

One option could be to use some GUID or pseudo-random identifier that you store the list under in the session.  This would allow the same action rendered from different browser tabs to store the differing results with differing identifiers.  The rendered results view would just need to store the identifier and be sure to provide it when the appropriate button was selected.

The concern here becomes how to cleanup the session, aka when do we know when that list of results is no longer needed?  Its not easy to determine.  Also, depending on the number of results per unique fetch you do, its unwise to place large lists inside an HTTP Session.  You ideally want to keep such sessions as lean as possible.

Should you be using an ORM framework, I would recommend you give consideration to the use of L2 caches.  Instead of trying to shoehorn your result storage to the HTTP session, the L2 cache would provide a way to cache query results.  The benefit here is that should different sessions run the same query, they benefit one another.

When using L2 cache, your action no longer would need to be concerned with the user's session.  The methods for export and search would be nearly identical.  They both would run the query, but the idea is that the results from the display would still be in the L2 cache, thus the call to export them would pull from the cache.

Even if you aren't using an ORM, you could still leverage using ehcache directly, managing the results associated to a given query and consulting the cache prior to the database.